# Is it correct to edit a question editing only tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I am a user of Earth Science Exchange. I will soon reach the privilege to edit questions with no need of aproval by rep users. I am graduated in geology and I see many incorrectly tagged questions related to my field of knowledge.

Is it correct to edit questions only changing the tags and not touching the body of the question?

Comment: I do this quite frequently, because `.net` users often tag `assembly` instead of `net-assembly` which is a totally different beast.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. Users with [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (10k on full-blown sites, 2k on beta sites like Earth Science) even have a special tool for this:

> #### Inline tag editing
>
> Finally, you now have the ability to do inline tag edits on questions: a new "Edit tags" link will appear next to the tags on every question; clicking it brings up an inline editor for the tags on that question:
>
> > [image]
>
> This allows you to quickly retag questions that need it, which you'll find especially useful combined with the list of new tags on the stats page.

Such a tool wouldn't make sense if it wouldn't be correct to leave the body (and the title) alone.

Of course, as with all edits, it's best to

1. try to improve as much as you can, *especially* when you don't have full edit privileges yet
2. not to edit too many questions at once, to avoid flooding the review queues and/or the homepage with old bumped questions

Comment: Aren't we sending an incorrect message to those who can only make edit suggestions? As I am sure you know, on SO these would be considered ["too minor"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381192/11407695). Shouldn't there be a big disclaimer that those without the privilege shouldn't be doing tag-only edits?

Comment: @OlegValter that's what point 1. in the last paragraph is aimed at. I think Stack Overflow is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: That's why I commented - I have serious doubts people are reading up to the last paragraph :) As a reviewer, I see a lot of such suggested edits usually eligible for immediate rejection. Would be sad if people started linking to this Q&A where both answers start with "yes" and only that + only yours even mentions the need to address other post issues when suggesting. P.s. Exception - that's saddening then...

Comment: @OlegValter the question asks about *edits*, and suggested edits are only part of those. Here on Meta, the community seems to be OK with these, see [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1406950/tag-only-suggested-edits). Even on Stack Overflow [most of them seem to be approved](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1406950/tag-only-suggested-edits). Proper tagging is important (but this is probably not the place to discuss how important it is).

Comment: Well, you got me interested - I will go make a query about the overall approval rate - what you linked gave me a couple of extra gray hairs in terms of the quality of suggestions that are approved. Re: edits - I know, the only problem I have is that the OP does not have the full edit privilege on any site (both of the profiles I managed to find), so it is highly likely they mean suggested edits - to which we, unfortunately, say that this is a-ok (I am not saying I think they are wrong, but a better emphasis on "try to fix everything" would send a better message).

Comment: @Oleg Valter I edited the question including I will reach that privilege soon. Is it better now? Glorfindel you may wish to include some aclarations after my edit.

Comment: @Universal_learner - I understand - my concern is not about you (I only referenced you because Glorfindel replied to me that this is about full edits, not suggestions), but about other users. We have enough too minor edit suggestions already, it doesn't help when we further endorse edits that forgo other problems with the post just to fix the tag by saying "yeah, go ahead, and, btw, once you get enough rep - go wild". And I don't even say this is wrong, I fear (as an editor and a reviewer) that those who make such suggestions will use such Q&As as their defence.

Comment: @Universal_learner - but thanks for editing the question, yes, I think it better conveys that you are asking about the full edit privilege :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In fact, part of the [10k privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (2k on beta sites) is inline tag editing, designed to make this even easier:

[image]